# Does PHP's ignore_user_abort only work if placed at the top/on first line?

Tags: php

The sample code on the PHP function page suggests this, but does not clarify this in the notes?

For example what if I only wanted ignore_user_abort(true); to initiate from about half way down onwards, would this work - or will it need to be at the top - and impact the entire thing?

Comment: What would be the reason for doing this?

Comment: In most web applications this function doesn't really do anything, as you are fulfilling a single request and would never no about the user doing something like navigating away from the pages.  What is you actual use case here?

Comment: I guess you can try to test this to see what happens.

Comment: @MikeBrant - about half way down on a specific PHP script I am running a few MySQL queries and then emailing the user, I have placed ignore_user_abort(true);  just before the few MySQL queries to ensure they get actioned and the user also gets emailed, if for whatever reason it does not get to about half way down it would not matter - as long as the MySQL queries and email was sent out together.

Comment: @RocketHazmat This is going to sound silly - but do you mean by accessing the relevant page of the PHP script in a browser - and quickly exiting it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard See my response to Mike Brant above, could only notify 1 programmer per comment.